# How to use my custom HTML Button on the rich text editor?

Tags: richtext

I made a custom HTML button in System Settings -> HTML Buttons

When going to a channel entry, the rich text editor still only displays the default buttons. I see no way of adding my custom one.

How can I add it?

Comment: Which EE version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Each member in your site may have his own set of formatting buttons, and
the setting in My Account page overrides the one in System settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the custom HTML buttons only work with the field type `Textarea`. Once you select that field at the bottom will be a box falled `Field tools` and then you select `Show formatting buttons`. That will show your custom HTML buttons you made in settings.

I wish they were added to the rich text editor as well, but they are not. And using the text area with your custom buttons just creates code which is also annoying when trying to hide the code from clients.

I'm on EE 5.2.3

If you want to create your own buttons for the rich text editor field type follow this page in the EE docs:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/rte-tools.html